# What is the best spot to free THTTPClient instance in async operation?

Tags: delphi

`THTTPClient` supports asynchronous operations.  For example:

```
var
  H: THTTPClient;
  A: IAsyncResult;
  r: IHTTPResponse;
begin
  H := THTTPClient.Create;
  A := H.BeginGet('http://localhost/get', nil);
  // P1
  r := THTTPClient.EndAsyncHTTP(A);
  ShowMessage(r.StatusCode.ToString);
  // P2
end;
```

The `H` instance isn't freed in the above code.  If I free `H` at P1, I receive an error that the HTTP operation has been cancelled. If I free `H` at P2, it works fine.

What if I want to execute an HTTP operation asynchronously, but later get the response in other method:

```
procedure ShowResponse(A: IAsyncResult);
var
  r: IHTTPResponse;
begin
  r := THTTPClient.EndAsyncHTTP(A);
  ShowMessage(r.StatusCode.ToString);
end;
```

How should I free the `H` instance?

Comment: I personally don't bother with all those pre-made components/objects/methods which "make it easier". The easiest way for me is to simply do it synchronously, from within a thread (even if it's anonymous), with some callback. Gives me better control over how things work But that's, like, my opinion though.

Comment: All `THTTPClient` examples I have seen use a persistent instance on a Form, not one created dynamically per request. I suggest you keep track of which `THTTPClient` object creates which `IAsyncResult` object, and when your async handler exits then you will know which `THTTPClient` to free.